# can't implement button movement when holding down the left mouse button

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, pyqt5

I am learning PyQt and I have a function in my program that creates buttons. Next, I try to access these buttons through a proxy in order to render the move, however for some reason it does not work

Here s my code/

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, intterface.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Создаем QGraphicsScene
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.scene, self)
        self.view.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.view.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self.dragging_proxy = None

        self.scene.setSceneRect(-10000, -10000, 20000, 20000)


        # Рисуем бесконечную сетку
        pen = QPen(QColor(20, 20, 20), 1, Qt.SolidLine)
        for x in range(-10000, 10000, 50):
            self.scene.addLine(x, -10000, x, 10000, pen)
        for y in range(-10000, 10000, 50):
            self.scene.addLine(-10000, y, 10000, y, pen)

        # Создаем QGraphicsView
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene, self)
        self.view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

        self.view.setStyleSheet("background-color: grey;")

        # Создаем QTreeView для отображения файлов и папок
        self.tree_view = QTreeView(self)
        self.tree_view.setRootIsDecorated(True)
        self.tree_view.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        # Создаем виджет с кнопками "Add Scene" и "Add Choice Scene"
        self.widget = QWidget(self.view)
        self.widget.setGeometry(0, 0, 150, 70)
        self.widget.hide()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        add_scene_button = QPushButton("Add Scene", self.widget)
        add_scene_choice_button = QPushButton("Add Choice Scene", self.widget)
        layout.addWidget(add_scene_button)
        layout.addWidget(add_scene_choice_button)

        # Создаем модель файловой системы для QTreeView
        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())
        self.tree_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree_view.setRootIndex(self.model.index(QDir.currentPath()))

        # Создаем панель инструментов для QTreeView
        dock = QDockWidget("Files", self)
        dock.setWidget(self.tree_view)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, dock)

        # Добавляем обработчики событий мыши
        self.view.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.view.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.view.viewport().setMouseTracking(True)
        self.view.mousePressEvent = self.mousePressEvent
        self.view.mouseMoveEvent = self.mouseMoveEvent
        self.view.wheelEvent = self.wheelEvent

    def add_button_to_scene(self):
        # Создаем объект кнопки
        button = QPushButton("Button")
        button.setFixedWidth(70)
        button.setFixedHeight(30)

        # Создаем графический прокси для кнопки
        proxy = QGraphicsProxyWidget()
        proxy.setWidget(button)

        # Получаем координаты курсора на сцене
        pos = self.view.mapToScene(self.view.mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos()))

        # Устанавливаем позицию кнопки на сцене
        proxy.setPos(pos)

        # Добавляем кнопку на сцену
        self.scene.addItem(proxy)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            items = self.scene.items(event.pos())
            for item in items:
                if isinstance(item, QGraphicsProxyWidget) and isinstance(item.widget(), QPushButton):
                    self.dragging_proxy = item
                    if event.modifiers() != Qt.ShiftModifier:
                        # сохраняем начальную позицию курсора
                        self.prev_pos = event.pos()
                    break
        if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            if event.modifiers() == Qt.ShiftModifier:
                # перемещение сцены
                self.prev_pos = event.pos()
            else:
                # отображение виджета
                pos = QCursor.pos()
                pos = self.view.mapFromGlobal(pos)
                pos = self.view.mapToScene(pos)
                pos = QPoint(round(pos.x()), round(pos.y()))
                self.widget.move(pos)
                self.widget.show()

        # обработка события контекстного меню
        if event.button() == Qt.RightButton and not event.modifiers():
            menu = QMenu(self)
            add_scene_action = menu.addAction("Add Scene")
            add_choice_scene_action = menu.addAction("Add Choice Scene")
            action = menu.exec_(self.view.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
            if action == add_scene_action:
                self.add_button_to_scene()
            elif action == add_choice_scene_action:
                self.add_button_to_scene()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.dragging_proxy is not None:
            # перемещаем прокси кнопки на новую позицию
            delta = event.pos() - self.prev_pos
            self.dragging_proxy.moveBy(delta.x(), delta.y())
            self.prev_pos = event.pos()
        else:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.dragging_proxy is not None:
            self.dragging_proxy = None
```

I tried tracking the cursor for other objects and it works for them, but since I have a limited number of buttons, this approach will not work. Help me please

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (emphasis on *minimal*). Also note that "monkey patching" event handler is generally discouraged (especially if done with event handlers of *another* object) as they are more difficult to debug and can create unexpected behavior, most importantly with complex widgets like scroll areas, which "redirect" events from their viewports. Besides, there's little point in doing for this case, just subclass QGraphicsView.